# Is there any way to avoid use of Ternary Operator?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

```
User.UserRoleID == 9 ? false : true
```

Suppose this is my condition and it is now using the ternary operator.
 Could someone suggest some other method other than If

Comment: What is the context of the code? Is it a return statement? Or something else that is being assigned this true/false value?

Comment: what is wrong with `if`?

Comment: You could replace your line of code with no code, It doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Jodrell: You really think `if (User.UserRoleID == 9) return false; else return true;` is much better?

Comment: I think Jodrell is making fun of the question and means actually to use no code at all (aka, the best way to not use the ternary operator).

Comment: @BoltClock, not without the newlines and braces. Anyway, a noop is better here.

Comment: Now I am *REALLY* curious about why not to use **if**...

Comment: I have never understood why many people are down on the ternary operator. In some situations (not necessarily this contrived one) it is entirely appropriate, and often more succinct than alternatives.

Comment: Hmm, before reading the OP, I thought, from the title (not sure why), the goal would be to avoid it so that branching could be avoided and the code made (possibly) faster during execution. Wasn't that, though.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just turn around the comparison:

```
bool b = User.UserRoleID != 9;
```

Comment: Yes, SO has gone wild, in the negative way. I wouldn't mind if it stopped at 0... @LukeG

Comment: I suggest putting parantheses arount `User.UserRoleID != 9` so that any reader of your code is confident you knew what you were doing. Especially in contexts where you can't see what type `b` is.

Comment: @LukeG It's boolean zen, and it is the most concise replacement for the given expression. So, some upvotes are in order, I think. The absolute number is, of course, always to be seen relative to the number of views. Excelent answer to unpopular question -> minimal reputation gain, good answer to a popular question -> rake in the rep!

Comment: @cmaster I do not doubt the correctness of the answer, nor do I think it does not deserve upvotes if it helped someone. I just find is interesting, that an answer as simple as this is able to collect that amount of upvotes (and 28 upvotes/200 views is a lot) in a community that is supposed to consist of experts.

Comment: @LukeG: An upvote is a judgement on the fit of the answer to the question not an assessment of the challenge of the problem posed. Simple answers to simple questions are therefore as worthy as anything else.

Comment: @LukeG An upvote is based on whether the individual answer for the individual question is thought to be "useful". The relative complexity of the question itself seems irrelevant, IMHO. Compare it to other answers, some of which try to be more creative, and this one seems more useful.

Comment: @ray this is the best and most useful for the very specific OP case, where you need true/false as each branch. For any other operation or value it wouldn't work, hence [the creative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43230021/4209853) and [the pragmatic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43229862/4209853) responses

Comment: @xDaizu Hence my explicitness about this being an "individual answer for the individual question". I know, and didn't suggest or imply, that this approach could be used in other contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Patrick Hofman's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43226822/4209853) is perfect for OP case, since it's *very specifically* returning true/false. For a more general case, **if is the way to go**:

```
User.UserRoleID == 9 ? doOneStuff() : doTheOtherStuff()
```

it can be easily substituted by the equivalent if/else

```
if(User.UserRoleID == 9){
   doOneStuff();
}else{
   doTheOtherStuff();
}
```

In case of assignments and returns, you need to express the left part in both branches:

```
 int foo = (User.UserRoleID == 9) ? doOneStuff() : doTheOtherStuff()

 if(User.UserRoleID == 9){
       int foo = doOneStuff();
    }else{
       int foo = doTheOtherStuff();
    }
```

In case of this ternary being a parameter you'll need to explicitely extract it to a variable:

```
int result = myFunction(User.UserRoleID == 9 ? 4 : 5)

 int parameter;
 if(User.UserRoleID == 9){
       parameter = 4;
    }else{
       parameter = 5;
    }
result = myFunction(parameter);
```

Answer (score 1):

[You should use an **if**. Seriously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43229862/4209853); but if for any reason you can't bring yourself to use that peasant *if* statement (¿?), you *could* use **switch**.

```
return (User.UserRoleID == 9) ? false : true

switch(User.UserRoleID == 9){
    case true:
        return true;
    case false:
        return false;
    default:
        //return... wait, what?
        throw new Exception("Boolean math broken. Please, restart the universe");
 }
```

For a more general case:

```
return (User.UserRoleID == 9) ? doOneThing(): doTheOtherThing();

switch(User.UserRoleID == 9){
    case true:
        return doOneThing();
    case false:
        return doTheOtherThing();
}
```

Some people don't like this switch approach. Well, you could also **try** this other one:

```
try {
    bool result = User.UserRoleID == 9;
    throw new Activator.CreateInstance(result.ToString() + "Exception");
} catch (TrueException e){
    return doOneThing();
}catch(FalseException e){
    return doTheOtherThing();
}
```

> Note: PLEASE, DON'T DO ANY OF THIS. You **can** do this, but it is horrible and you'll be despised (and probably fired) if they see this code. Ye be warned

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is it because it's a horrible way to do anything and it hurts just to see it? It is! And it does! ..but OP don't want to use proper ifs!

Comment: A `switch`… for a boolean. With a default for a third case… for a boolean. Please use an `if` instead.

Comment: Okay, I didn't spot that OP is looking for a solution that does not involve an `if`. In this case this answer deserves an up vote for creativity.

Comment: @DarkDust Not saying this is a good answer, but what other alternative is there to perform the work of an `if` without using `if` or ternary operator? I'd at least made that `default` case throw an exception. (I'd still prefer Hoffman's answer, though)

Comment: The default is intended as a joke... yeah, you can throw an exception, return null, whatever. Is not supposed to happen. Like... ever.

Comment: *"Your engineers were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn't stop to think if they should."*

Comment: @ray: Isn't the switch conclusive and the `default` therefor unnecessary (and unreachable)? Don't have a C# compiler at hand, but I guess you can remove it without the compiler complaining.

Comment: @DarkDust You're right, but making obvious things obvious can help. I've often seen assertions meant to fail added as a safety net in case unreachable code is reached somehow (e.g. someone modified a part of the code, but not another, and introduced a bug)

Answer (score 0):

How about just using `User.UserRoleID == 9` in place of the `true` or `false` literals? Not ideal if this ends up repeating throughout the code, but if you only need it once or twice...